# How to use uncss by addy osmani with a Single Page MEAN stack application

Tags: css, angularjs, gruntjs, single-page-application, ngroute

I've created a application using the MEAN stack which was generated by Yeoman [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack)

I would love to include [uncss](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss) to my grunt build.

Unfortunately, this is not possible given that the site is SPA.
I've read that I can generate a site map and then use that through uncss; however, could someone please implement uncss and help me through this process for I dont know how to really start?

Comment: You will probably have to use a headless browser to capture a static version of your site then use uncss on that.

Comment: how would I go about learning how to capture a static version of my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `uncss` at a command line or with `grunt-uncss`...although the latter has open issues.  The example on the `grunt-uncss` page you mention, using a WordPress sitemap , is helpful but doesn't clearly explain what to do about SPA's.  Hopefully this helps.

**1) Command line**

As the [docs on the github page](https://github.com/giakki/uncss#from-the-command-line) explain, you can now pass URL's directly into uncss to generate css output.  You can pass URL's to uncss instead of files...

Thus, if your SPA is simple enough, you could use the core `uncss` app like this:

`uncss http://localhost:3000/mycoolapp > stylesheet.css`

**2) grunt-uncss**

At the time of writing this answer, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss/issues/83) with `grunt-uncss` that needs to be known to use uncss via grunt.

While the `url` option is depreciated, the alternative approach to put the URL's into the `file` array won't work because of the open issue.  However, the `url` option can [still be used](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss#options) so that an array of URL's can be checked.  In this case, the `Gruntfile.js` would have a section like this:

```
uncss: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      ...some options...
      urls         : ['http://localhost:3000/mycoolapp', '...'], // This is the line you need
      ...even more options...
    },
```

The array in `urls` would need to contain a list of urls.  Given that this plugin is still in development, you should watch the github page so you are notified of potentially breaking changes as it builds upon v.0.3.x...

**Two notes:**

- phantom.js will be used for this processing, so as long as your SPA is friendly enough that phantom can do it's work...this should work for you.
- you have to enter the array of urls by hand, which is what the WordPress example off the `grunt-css` page is automating...so if you can similarly automate, life will be easier.